# Haskell create an n-ary tuple from given input

Tags: list, haskell

To put it straigth, I'm fairly new to Haskell and trying to solve a problem (programming exercise) I came over. Where it says I should create a function

```
com :: Int -> [t] -> [[t]]
```

that returns all possible choices of n elements, where n and list are the first and second arguments, respectively. Elements can be picked over again and in a different order. A result would be like:

```
com 2 [1,2,3] = [[1,1], [1,2]..[3,3]]
```

For the cases n = 1 and n = 2, I manage to solve the cases. The case  n = 1 is quite simple, and, for the case n = 2, I would use concatenation and build it up. However, I don't understand how it can be made n-ary and work for all n. Like if suddenly a function call would be like `com 10` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
> sequence (replicate 3 "abc")
["aaa","aab","aac","aba","abb","abc","aca","acb","acc"
,"baa","bab","bac","bba","bbb","bbc","bca","bcb","bcc"
,"caa","cab","cac","cba","cbb","cbc","cca","ccb","ccc"]
```

The above exploits the fact that `sequence`, in the list monad, builds the cartesian product of a list of lists. So, we can simply replicate our list `n` times, and then take the product.

(Note that `"abc"` above is a shorthand for the list of charatcters `['a','b','c']`)

So, a solution could be

```
com n xs = sequence (replicate n xs)
```

or equivalently, as Daniel Wagner points out below,

```
com = replicateM
```

A final note: I do realize that this is probably not very helpful for actually *learning* how to program. Indeed, I pulled two "magic" functions from the library which solved the task. Still, it shows how the problem can be reduced to two subproblems: 1) replicating a value `n` times and 2) building a cartesian product. The second task is a nice exercise on its own, if you don't want to use the library. You may wish to solve that starting from:

```
sequence :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sequence []     = [[]]
sequence (x:xs) = ...
       where ys = sequence xs
```

Comment: `replicateM n = sequence . replicate n`

Answer (score 2):

First: `[]` is a list constructor, not a tuple.  I don't know any general way to build n-ary tuple.

However, sticking to lists, if you have `n = 1` case solved and `n = 2` case solved try to express the latter in term of the former.  Then generalize to any `n` in terms of `n-1`:

```
com n xs = concat [map (x:) (com (n-1) xs) | x <- xs ]
```

Comment: Ole already stated that he got base case solved. Question was about general case.

Answer (score 1):

A more verbose way to write it, but potentially more helpful when trying to understand `List` non-determinism and trying to understand exactly what the Haskell comprehension syntactic sugar really means, is to write with `do` notation:

```
com :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
com 0 _  = []
com 1 xs = [[x] | x <- xs]
com n xs = do
    x <- xs
    let ys = com (n - 1) xs
    map (x:) ys
```

Comment: I think it's more logical to have `com 0 _ = [[]]`, then you don't need the 1 case.

Comment: I'm indifferent. I interpret `com 0 _` as basically a no-op, so nothing should have to be checked about what it returns to see that it was a no-op. If it returns `[[]]` you have to write a lot of code downstream to handle that unusual case. I could see it going either way. I'd rather write one extra line in this case, and have a bang-simple pattern match for the no-op everywhere else downstream, than to squeeze one measly line out of this for possibly the cost of dealing with `[[]]` in lots of other places.